# Django named urls, generic views?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

So, here is one of my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('items.views',
    url(r'^(?P<item_id>[\d+])/$', 'view_listing', name="item_view"),
)
```

And in my template, I can do this: `<a href="{% url item_view 1 %}">here</a>` and I'll get a link to the right page. Everything works great!

But, here is another one

```
urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.list_detail',
    (r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', 'object_detail', dict(page_info, slug_field='slug'), "page_view"),
)
```

But in my template if I try this: `<a href="{% url page_view slug='TermsAndConditions' %}">Terms and Conditions</a>` or this `<a href="{% url page_view 'TermsAndConditions' %}">Terms and Conditions</a>` it errors out with this error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /

Could not parse the remainder: ''TermsAndConditions '' from ''TermsAndConditions ''
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to use named urls with generic views and the `url` template tag like this? Or the right way to get it to work with generic views?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is

```
<a href='{% url page_view slug="TermsAndConditions" %}'>Terms and Conditions</a>
```

Comment: Who would have thought such a simple solution as changing the types of quotes would be the fix. I'm not even working on the site anymore, but in any case, I did a quick test, and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The template system in Django only supports double quotes, which explains the syntax error you get when using single quotes. You will need to do

```
{% url page_view slug="TermsAndConditions" %}
```

If you omit the quotes, Django things you're referring to a *variable* named `TermsAndConditions`.

Comment: I had tried this before as well, and it also does not work. I get this error:
TemplateSyntaxError at /

Caught an exception while rendering: Reverse for 'listitstolen.page_view' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'slug': u'TermsAndConditions'}' not found.

Comment: Strange. This works for me—I put the URLconf for page_view in an empty project and tried the template code in a shell—the reverse worked. Try using url() in the URLconf (although I guess it make no difference...) and try also the positional version: {% url page_view "TermsAndConditions" %}

Comment: Still didn't work. Not sure how it worked for you and not for me, but this wouldn't be the first time in programming that this is the case. I wonder what is different between out implementations. U were able get it to work using the generic detail view? Here is my code http://dpaste.com/hold/15428/

Answer (score 0):

Don't put quotation marks around the string "TermsAndConditions":

```
{% url page_view slug=TermsAndConditions %}
```

Comment: This gives me a different error now.

TemplateSyntaxError at /

Caught an exception while rendering: Reverse for 'listitstolen.page_view' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'slug': ''}' not found.

Comment: Sorry, do it with double quotes. I thought it was a variable you were trying to use.

Comment: I had tried this before as well, and it also does not work. I get this error:
TemplateSyntaxError at /

Caught an exception while rendering: Reverse for 'listitstolen.page_view' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'slug': u'TermsAndConditions'}' not found.